# How to set a certain element from multiple lists to a single variable

Tags: python

I have a few lists:

```
['undergraduate', '1110', 'Computer Science I', '2 4 0', 'BA', 'none']
['undergraduate', '1120', 'Computer Science II', '2 4 0', 'none', '1110']
['undergraduate', '3310', 'Data and File Structures', '1 3 0', 'none', '1310, 1120']
['undergraduate', '1310', 'Foundations of Computer Sci', '1 4 0', 'C', 'none']
['graduate', '5091', 'Computer Science Seminar', '1 2 0 seminar', 'none', '3310']
```

The 4th element in each list is the grade for the class the list describes. Is there a way to assign them to the same variable, grade, while still having the ability to distinguish which class it's from? If grade != "none" then I need to return True. 
I've done it manually, but I'm not sure how to do it a better way.
My code:

```
if class1[4] != "none":
    True
else:
    False

if class2[4] != "none":
    True
else:
    False
```

Later on I will need to be able to call class1 and class2 separately and determine if they have grades and what those grades are.

Comment: Don't use multiple variables, use a list of lists.

Comment: Then you can make a list of the grades from the list of lists.

Comment: You can take this a step further and use a list of dicts or a list of objects. Also, I suggest using the value `null` rather than the string `"none"` for empty values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to check if any or all of the grades are `"none"`, you can use the `any` and `all` builtins in python with a quick list comprehension:

```py
# get the grades

grades = [class_list[4] for class_list in [class1, class2, ...]]

# check whether the grades are "none"

are_grades_none = [grade == "none" for grade in grades]
```

Now, if you want to return `False` if *any* of the grades are `"none"`:

```py
return not any(are_grades_none)
```

Or if you want to return `False` if *all* of the grades are `"none"`:

```py
return not all(are_grades_none)
```